# What is the Android equivalent of display:none in CSS?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the android equivalent of the CSS style attribute display:none?

In web pages the display:none stylesheet causes the web page element to which it is applied to be hidden and not occupy any space. When the element's attribute is changed dynamically using Javascript to visible, the browser shows the element moving any other elements surrounding it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you can use `setVisibility` on a view.
There are 3 options available 

VISIBLE - seen by the user

INVISIBLE - not seen by the user. But the view still takes some space.

GONE - not seen by the user, and the view doesn't take up any space.

---

Adding examples

**4 Text views in a `LinearLayout` oriented vertically, all visible**

[image: All visible text views code] [image: All visible text views on dev]

**4 Text views in a `LinearLayout` oriented vertically, 2 set to invisible**
[image: 2 text views invisible code] [image: 2 text views invisible on dev]

**4 Text views in a `LinearLayout` oriented vertically, 2 set to gone**
[image: 2 text views gone code] [image: 2 text views gone on dev]

Comment: @T.Todua added example code, with a screenshot of how they would look on a device

Answer (score 11):

`android:visibility="gone"`

or in code: `[element].setVisibility(View.GONE);`

This is the equivalent of display:none in CSS.

There's also `android:visibility="invisible"` or `.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` which is the equivalent of visibility:hidden in CSS - i.e. the element is hidden but still takes up space in the layout.

[setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) Android docs

[android:visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) docs

Comment: Should be android:visibility="gone" not android:visibilty="gone"

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
button.setVisibility(view.GONE);
```

Also

```
button.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
button.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
```